# Don't know why I get Glibc detected error

Tags: c, pointers, glibc

This is my function which causes the error

```
void copy_bounds_concrete(char* lower, char* upper, struct bounds* results){
   if (DEBUG)
      printf("%d %d \n", strlen(lower), strlen(upper));
   (*results).lowerBound =(char*) malloc(strlen(lower));
   strcpy((*results).lowerBound, lower);

   (*results).upperBound =(char*) malloc(strlen(upper));
   strcpy((*results).upperBound, upper);
}
```

and this is the struct bounds:

```
struct bounds
{
   char* name;
   char* lowerBound;
   char* upperBound;
}
```

I don't know why I got this pointer error. I have spent couple of hours to figure out but get nothing.

Comment: Don't cast malloc in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a +1 to all the `strlen` inside `malloc`, otherwise you don't allocate space for the string terminator (`strlen` returns the "logical length" of the string, not including the trailing NUL, so you allocate less memory than needed, which gives you that error).

Incidentally, instead of `(*result).` you can do `result->`